# Simple problems with adding checkbox using js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using JS to create some elements - checkbox + some value from input.

My code to create checkbox is:

```
const checkboxOfTask = document.createElement('input');
checkboxOfTask.type = "checkbox";
checkboxOfTask.id = "checkboxOfTask";
```

then i want to add it and value from text input to html like this:

```
addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const newTask = document.createElement('li');
    if (taskDateInput.value == "") {
        newTask.innerText = checkboxOfTask + taskInput.value;
    } else {
        newTask.innerText = checkboxOfTask + taskInput.value + " - " + taskDateInput.value;
    }
```

Then when i look at my project the list shows me "[object HTMLInputElement]sometxt".
Now when i look at it i think the problem is in newTask.innerText because i'm adding it to innerText, but i don't know how to do it correctly.

Comment: What did you expect to get from `checkboxOfTask + taskInput.value`? `checkboxOfTask` is not string. It is HTML input element.

Comment: Yup, now i know it that this is the problem. After click button i want to see in my list new element that contains checkbox and taskInput.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkbox `checkboxOfTask` is not string. It is HTML input element. You can't insert HTML element into the `innerText`.

You are looking for `appendChild()` function. In your example it should be: **`newTask.appendChild(checkboxOfTask)`**. Also you have to create new checkbox for each task.

I've created simple example:

```js
const addTaskButton = document.getElementById('add');
const taskDateInput = document.getElementById('taskDateInput');
const taskInput = document.getElementById('taskInput');
const taskList = document.getElementById('taskList');

addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // ↓ li
    const newTask = document.createElement('li');
    // ↓ checkbox
    const checkboxOfTask = document.createElement('input')
    checkboxOfTask.type = "checkbox";
    // ↓ span
    const someSpan = document.createElement('span');
    someSpan.innerText = taskInput.value + (taskDateInput.value?' - '+taskDateInput.value:'');
    // ↓ append
    newTask.appendChild(checkboxOfTask);
    newTask.appendChild(someSpan);
    taskList.appendChild(newTask); 
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="add">add</button>
<input type="date" id="taskDateInput"/>
<input type="text" id="taskInput"/>

<ul id="taskList">
</ul>
```